# How should I pass an error message to the top method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

A method have some methods and also some methods have other methods.
How should I pass an error message to the top method to show the message on the window or the dialog box? 
It may not be an error message but an caution message or something.
It would be really nice if you give me an advice about ASP.NET MVC. In ASP.NET MVC, action methods would be the top.

Comment: Does a standard "Try, Catch (Throw), Finally" not meet your requirement?

Comment: Please read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: "A method have some methods and also some methods have some methods." - *Head Exploded*

Comment: @KingCronus... a Stack Overflow? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `TryXXX` pattern:

```
public bool TryXXX(InputType input, out ResultType result, out string errorMessage);
```

and in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{

    ResultType result;
    out string errorMessage;
    if (!TryXXX(input, out result, out errorMessage))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMessage);
        return View();
    }

    // here you could use the result
    ...

}
```

Another possibility is to pass the `ModelState` to the lower layers which will take care of adding the error messages to it so that in your controller action you just need to check `ModelState.IsValid` after calling some method.

Yet another possibility is to use exceptions but remember that exceptions should be used only to handle exceptional cases. They should be avoided to handle business validation.

There really are different ways and it all depend on what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do a single try catch at the highest method alone.

In regards to MVC and asp.net you don't want to show the errors to the end user. And warnings are best prevented with validation up front in the form.

As a last note, if you really need to show the warnings to the end user then:

- Create a public variable called string "WarningMessage"
- Reset the value before your process starts
- Assign/append warnings to the variable inside each method that has a warning
- Check if WarningMessage has value in the return view.
- If it has value display the message

Answer (score 0):

Throw a custom exception where u want

```
throw new Exception("Message");
```

By default the exception will bubble all the way to the top of the stack (i.e display a server error page) unless you catch it somewhere in your code

```
try{
  //code
} catch (Exception e) {
  //use exception to display the message
}
```

The exception can be thrown from any sub method and caught by the parent method

Answer (score 0):

in inner methods use:

```
HttpContext.Current.AddError(new Exception("error Message"));
```

in Controller method:

```
foreach (var item in HttpContext.AllErrors)
{
    //item is Exception
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done very easily using Javascript

```
var errorflag= false;
var msg='';
if(Failedcondition){
errorflag=true;
msg='Please verfiy first.';
}
if(SecondFailedCondition){
errorflag=true;
msg='Please verfiy first.';

}
else
{
other conditions
}
```